# Abstract class and an inheritor: is it possible to "pull up" .parent() here?

Tags: java, refactoring

Here are what I think are the relevant parts of the code of these two classes. First, `TreePointer` (original source [here](https://raw.github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils/1600ee84656e2bcfdff8444bfd19a2a28a250dad/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jackson/jsonpointer/TreePointer.java)):

```
public abstract class TreePointer<T extends TreeNode>
    implements Iterable<TokenResolver<T>>
{
    //...

    /**
     * What this tree can see as a missing node (may be {@code null})
     */
    private final T missing;

    /**
     * The list of token resolvers
     */
    protected final List<TokenResolver<T>> tokenResolvers;

    /**
     * Main protected constructor
     *
     * <p>This constructor makes an immutable copy of the list it receives as
     * an argument.</p>
     *
     * @param missing the representation of a missing node (may be null)
     * @param tokenResolvers the list of reference token resolvers
     */
    protected TreePointer(final T missing,
        final List<TokenResolver<T>> tokenResolvers)
    {
        this.missing = missing;
        this.tokenResolvers = ImmutableList.copyOf(tokenResolvers);
    }

    /**
     * Alternate constructor
     *
     * <p>This is the same as calling {@link #TreePointer(TreeNode, List)} with
     * {@code null} as the missing node.</p>
     *
     * @param tokenResolvers the list of token resolvers
     */
    protected TreePointer(final List<TokenResolver<T>> tokenResolvers)
    {
        this(null, tokenResolvers);
    }

    //...

    /**
     * Tell whether this pointer is empty
     *
     * @return true if the reference token list is empty
     */
    public final boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return tokenResolvers.isEmpty();
    }

    // .iterator(), .equals(), .hashCode(), .toString() follow
}
```

Then, `JsonPointer`, which contains this `.parent()` method which I'd like to factorize here (original source [here](https://raw.github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils/1600ee84656e2bcfdff8444bfd19a2a28a250dad/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jackson/jsonpointer/JsonPointer.java):

```
public final class JsonPointer
    extends TreePointer<JsonNode>
{
    /**
     * The empty JSON Pointer
     */
    private static final JsonPointer EMPTY
        = new JsonPointer(ImmutableList.<TokenResolver<JsonNode>>of());

    /**
     * Return an empty JSON Pointer
     *
     * @return an empty, statically allocated JSON Pointer
     */
    public static JsonPointer empty()
    {
        return EMPTY;
    }

    //...

    /**
     * Return the immediate parent of this JSON Pointer
     *
     * <p>The parent of the empty pointer is itself.</p>
     *
     * @return a new JSON Pointer representing the parent of the current one
     */
    public JsonPointer parent()
    {
        final int size = tokenResolvers.size();
        return size <= 1 ? EMPTY
            : new JsonPointer(tokenResolvers.subList(0, size - 1));
    }

    // ...
}
```

As mentioned in the subject, the problem I have here is with `JsonPointer`'s `.parent()` method. In fact, the logic behind this method applies to all `TreeNode` implementations. Except that I have to use a constructor, and of course such a constructor is implementation dependent :/

Is there a way to implement `.parent()` so that each implementation of `TreeNode` recieve an instance of itself and not `TreeNode`, or is it just a pipe dream?

Comment: I've never seen the term _[factorize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorize)_ used in computer science. I think you meant _[refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactor)_.

Comment: @DennisTraub sorry, but I don't see how this relates to the question at all? Have you seen the original source at least? I don't believe _one_ comment is misplaced at all.

Comment: @DaoWen by this I mean "make it common", just like in math you factorize `(a*x) + (b*x)` into `(a+b)*x`

Comment: @fge - Sure, we can guess that's what you meant based on the math term—but that doesn't mean it's the right term to use in OOP. _Factorize_ makes specific reference to the term _factor_, as in _factor * factor = product_. What you're talking about is called [pull up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_Up_refactoring) in OOP.

Comment: @DaoWen OK, I'm French, so some OOP vocabulary subtleties in English are still escaping me ;) Editing the question with the correct vocables...

Comment: @fge - Interesting! Do you use the French equivalent of the word "factorize" this way in French?

Comment: @DaoWen pretty much so, yes: to "factorize" code, in French, means to "make some code common", so I guess the equivalent OOP parlance is "pull up"

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can add an `abstract` method `parent` to the `TreePointer` superclass. The real question is, does that make sense? We don't really have enough context here to know if it makes sense or not.

If it does make sense for all cases of `TreePointer`, then go ahead and add an `abstract` method `parent` to `TreePointer` and add a concrete implementation in all the subclasses. Alternatively, you could put a default implementation in `TreePointer` and override it where you want to provide different behavior in a subclass.

---

> Also, how do I make sure that for an implementation X of TreeNode, the
>   return type is X and not TreeNode? That is my problem, ultimately.

In the `TreePointer` class you would just make a method `public TreePointer<T> parent()`. You should be able to make all the code generic there, except for the `new new JsonPointer(...)` part. You'll probably have to refactor that into a separate method (probably `protected`) which you can override in each of your concrete subclasses.

---

Since you want to return `JsonPointer` and not `TreePointer<T>` in the subclass, and you also have the issue with needing (non-static) factory methods, I think your original suspicion was pretty much right. You *can* make this work with an abstract implementation in the parent, but you'd need to override it to provide more specific return types in the child classes, I don't think it's worth the trouble. Just declare a `public abstract TreePointer<T> parent()` in `TreePointer` and override it with `public JsonPointer parent()` in `JsonPointer`.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to `@Override` it since it will be common anyway. So what? Make `TreePointer` "non abstract"? If that is the only solution, why not...

Comment: Also, how do I make sure that for an implementation `X` of `TreeNode`, the return type is `X` and not `TreeNode`? That is my problem, ultimately.

Comment: @fge - An abstract class doesn't need all abstract methods. In fact, in Java 8 they're making it so even an interface can have concrete methods.

Comment: I _know_ that. If you look at the full code (links are provided), you will see that plenty of methods in `TreeNode` are even `final` ;)

Comment: @fge - OK—then I'm not sure why you thought I was suggesting you make it non-abstract. Anyway, I've edited my answer to address your follow-up question about the return type..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a factory method on JsonPointer that way you don't have to use a constructor and can be implementation independent.

Comment: Look at the original source: I can build JSON Pointers using `JsonPointer.of(...)` and others. I don't believe a factory will help in any way there.